# I want to export Glass

Tags: export, transparency, glass

I made some architecture and there are glasses of course.
And I want to export my architecture asset.
I tried every format and found that fbx or gltf can export my asset as own state.
But If I export as Gltf or Glb, MY glass transparency doesn't work.
Glass just looks like a basic white texture.So I find the way to solve
Some people say about alpha blend but I can't find alpha blend maybe because of the version
Some people recommand to change the format but I can't find a format including texture
Some people say that gltf cannot apply transmission so I changed but it didn't work.
I'm trying to find the resolution for 4hour and I'm getting crazy
PLEASE tell me just the way to the simplest way to make transparent materials that can be exported.

Comment: Did you try to adjust the material in the target software, where you import the file? Blender shaders are only compatible with Blender, so if you export it to any format you will have a lot of data loss in the shaders in any case.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures